# How to get an Iron Golem Spawner in 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to spawn in a spawner that spawns iron golems. I have tried and failed at changing the commands from previous versions to 1.13 because of the slight syntax change.

I tried to use the 1.10 command:

```
setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:"VillagerGolem"}}
```

I tried:

```
setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner{SpawnData:{id:"VillagerGolem"}} replace
```

in 1.13

but that crashed the game.

Comment: It would help us answer if you edit your question with the commands you've tried. It's easier to fix a command when someone can see what exactly is wrong.

Comment: What error message do you get? What part do you have problems with? Have you tried [this page](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk_format#Block_entity_format)?

Comment: For example, I tried to use the 1.10 command

Comment: setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {SpawnData:{id:"VillagerGolem"}}

Comment: which is setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner{SpawnData:{id:"VillagerGolem"}} replace in 1.13

Comment: Another command created a spawn egg, and the game said there is no option as minecraft:spawn_egg

Comment: Adding that info to your question would go a long way towards us being able to help you.

Comment: All help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You were very close.  You had the [entity ID](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Java_Edition_data_values/Entity_IDs) wrong.  The entity ID for the golem is *villager_golem*.  Capitalization and the underscore matter.

This command functions properly:

```
/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:mob_spawner{SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:villager_golem"}} replace
```

Answer (score 3):

The above answer may have been right at that time, however, now in 1.13.2 the command for this is as follows:

/setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:spawner{SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:iron_golem"}} replace

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, on the current Minecraft version 1.13.2,
Microsoft has changed a few entity IDs.
So now this command looks like this:

> /setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:spawner{SpawnData:{id:"minecraft:iron_golem"}} replace

Comment: How is this answer any different than @Jim's answer?